# Serial Communication in Raspberry pi 3 B+

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gsm, serial-communication, gprs

I want to communicate between Raspberry pi 3 B+ and GSM GPRS A6. I tried and I am unable to send data to GPRS Module from Raspberry pi.

Now, I know that GPIO serial port is disabled by default in newer Operating Systems (in my case Raspbian Stretch), so I have enabled it by adding following line in config.txt file,

```
enable_uart=1
```

Here's my Code:

```
import serial
import time

port = "/dev/ttyS0"
COMM = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200)

while(1):
    COMM.write("AT\r")
    print (COMM.read(5))
```

This command is supposed to return "OK", but it does not and nothing is printed. I am using python 2.7.

Some people suggested me to send data using this method,

```
COMM.write('AT' + '\r')
```

I tried but it didn't help.

There is no problem with my GPRS module. It works file with arduino.
So, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `pi` user doesn't have write access, try with `sudo python yourScript.py`. If that works, add `pi` user to `dialout` group `sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

First , be sure to enable the Serial.

**sudo raspi-config** -> Interfacing Option -> Serial

Second , **sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt**

Delete "console=serial,115200"

And Then
**sudo nano /boot/config.txt**

Add the end

dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
core_freq=250

While you use : Serial(/dev/**ttyAMA0**,9600)

Answer (score 1):

try sending:

```
import serial

port = "/dev/ttyS0"
comm = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200)

while True:
   comm.write('AT' + '\n\r')
   msg = comm.readline()
   print(msg)
```