# where can I find docs for the `serial` library?

Tags: python, documentation

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 to communicate with a GSM module over the GPIO pins. The operating system on the Pi is Raspbian Stretch. It has Python 2.7 installed. The standard way to communicate over the GPIO is using the `serial` library in Python which is pre-installed. I'm just trying to find the documentation for this library and can't find it anywhere.

Where is it?

I've tried googling for it and it only turns up a library called `pyserial` and examples of people using and [trying to use the `serial` library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968518/serial-communication-in-raspberry-pi-3-b) but no documentation for it in sight.

Comment: There isn't even a `README` in this library... But you can generate the doc by yourself lol. As the code has docstring, you can use `sphinx` and `autodoc` to generate a doc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the library `serial` is a bit too new, and since it has been developed by one single person, it might take time to get some documentation. What you can do is to have a quick overview of the project and its source code: https://bitbucket.org/davebelais/serial

Comment: That looks like it might be the wrong library since it's only a few months old, but people have been using the one I'm talking about for years. Heres an example from 2016: https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=16325

Answer (score 0):

I turns out it's at
https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/
which is where you end up when you're googling, but I naturally ignored it assuming that the name of the library would be whatever you write in the import statement. Clearly this doesn't hold for python.